# Why doesn't Console.Writeline, Console.Write work in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just open a console application and I type

```
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

But the output window doesn't show this. I go to the output window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>.

But nothing shows up when I run my program. Am I nuts or is this not supported in [Visual Studio 2010 Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express)?

Comment: As `Leif` said it disappears before you can see it. Use `Console.ReadKey()`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1583569/503688 for a mechanism to redirect console output to the debug output window.

Answer (score 392, accepted):

[`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) writes your output to the console window opened by your application (think black window with white text that appears when you open the Command Prompt.) Try [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) instead.

Comment: The debug output appears in the Output window (Debug => Windows => Output). Mine wasn't open by default.

Comment: If there is no output in the console window, also check the properties of the application under the Debug tab Start Options to make sure you do not have any command line arguments redirecting the output from the console.

Comment: And use a tool like https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx DebugView (dbgview) to receive the debug messages because they won't appear on the cmd console.

Comment: Well, if you "start without debugging", you will not see the output....So you have to run your program by "start debugging"...Sounds silly, but I just know that....And don't forget to select "Debug"  from the "Show output from" in the output window (In my case, the original tab is "Build")

Comment: While this was not the actual problem for mine, But two steps you can check. 
1: that you have not redirected the output via `Options->Debugging->General->Redirect all output window text to...`.
2: in my case, i did not have the DEBUG constant defined (check project options) / Result of having it in RELEASE

Answer (score 44):

No satisfactory answers were provided.

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` will write messages to the Output:debug window, but so much crap is constantly dumped into that window by every process under the sun, it is like finding a needle in a haystack to find *your* messages.

`Console.WriteLine()` does not write to any window in Visual Studio. I guess it will only write to the application console if your application creates a console in the first place, i.e. if it is a console application.

Comment: You could prefix your message with a string, e.g. ">>>"  and use [VSColorOutpu](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeWard-AnnArbor.VSColorOutput) to highlight such lines.

Comment: If you right click in the output window you can turn of all of the usual spammers (closing threads, loaded modules, etc).

Comment: In my case, the output appeared in the "Immediate" window.

Comment: Also, in vs2022 dotnet 4.8 wpf project it works (console.writeline is visible in output)
but not in c# 7.0 wpf project)

Answer (score 31):

Go to properties in you own project in the [Solution Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools) window and choose application type and look for *Output Type*.

Change its value to *Console Application*.

This will make console screen besides your form. If you close the console screen, your form will be closed too.

Comment: Make my day! I can loop through my LINQ query and write to the console now which is quick cheap way of getting the correct data into the fray.

Comment: 1. It works for VS Enterprise as well.
2. This solution redirects messages not to Output/Debug window of VS, but to a separately opened console window. The latter is often even more convenient. Good!

Comment: OMFG, this was it, I initially had the project at .NET Core 3.1, I switched to .NET 8 and it reset the `Output type` to `Windows Application`! It was just opening and exiting without throwing any message and it won't print any `Console.WriteLine` either! Gawd!!!!!

Answer (score 24):

Perhaps the console is clearing.  Try:

```
Console.WriteLine("Test");
Console.ReadLine();
```

And it will hopefully stay there until you press enter.

Answer (score 8):

Or you can debug by **`CTRL+F5`** this will open ConsoleWindow waits after last line executed untill you press key.

Comment: Well, that's not really 'debugging', that's just launching the application without attaching the debugger. :/

Answer (score 6):

It's more than likely because you've used `Console` in the namespace. For example like this:

```
namespace XYZApplication.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            //Some code;             
       }
    }
}
```

Try removing it from the namespace **or** use the full namespace instead i.e.

```
   System.Console.Writeline("abc");
```

The reason is a problem this is an issue is because you might have another clashing namespace. Example:

```
using System;
using AnotherNamespaceThatContainsAConsoleClass;
```

Comment: I didn't have any other Console in my app, but adding `System.` helped. Thanks.

Comment: *Why* is using Console a problem? What is the explanation? What are the mechanisms? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30298179/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen - have updated the response to include why using console is a problem. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 6):

I run into a similar problem while running a [unit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). `Console.WriteLine()` did not write anything into the Visual Studio *Output Window*.

Using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The output window isn't the console. Try the methods in `System.Diagnostics.Debug`

Answer (score 5):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. It will hold your screen until you press any key.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 5):

In a [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application, both methods,

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("my string")
```

and

```
System.Console.WriteLine("my string")
```

write to the output window.

In an [ASP.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core) application, only `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("my string")` writes to the output window.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project in [Solution Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools) and click "Clean".

Now run - press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Make sure the code is as below:

```
Console.WriteLine("TEST");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

**None of the answers here worked for me!!** Most of these people here are stuck in Windows Desktop Application *Consoleland*. If you are a `web developer` using **ASP.NET** in Visual Studio and do not see any console or debug text, here is how to fix that:

1. Paste the following two tests into your code so it runs both lines. These are tests for the output window:

   **System.Console.WriteLine($"hello console!");**

   **System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"hello debugger!");**
2. In Visual Studio choose VIEW > OUTPUT. You will see the results above in this output window after changing two settings below.
3. When NOT DEBUGGING, in the OUTPUT window at the top under "Show Output From" choose: "**YourProjectName - ASP.NET CORE Web Server**". Run your code. You should see the "Console" text above.
4. When DEBUGGING, in the OUTPUT window at the top under "Show Output From" choose: "**Debugger**". Run your code in debug mode. You should see the "Debug" text above.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ctrl-F5 (start without debugging) it will leave the console window open with a message "Press any key to continue".  That's the easiest way to keep the console window from closing so you can see the console output.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Debug menu and select Options and uncheck "Redirect all Output Window text to Immediate Window"

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or navigate to the *Debug* tab → *Windows* → *Immediate*.

In your code write:

```cs
Trace.WriteLine("This is one of the workarounds");
```

Comment: Where is the "*Debug* tab*"? What window / menu?

Comment: to be honest, this worked for me! The output tab still remains empty, but the immediate window is being populated even with console.writeline

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Writeline()` shows up in the debug output (Debug => Windows => Output).

Comment: No, System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine writes to Debug => Windows => Output, but not Console.WriteLine

Comment: The person asking the question is using a Console application, where Console.WriteLine() of course writes to the Console, which is the black coloured application window, looking like a DOS window. Console.WriteLine() only writes to the Debug Output Window, when it is not a Console application.

Comment: "Console.WriteLine() only writes to the Debug Output Window, when it is not a Console application." Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a command line application, you can also use `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your code to wait for the 'Enter' keypress before closing the console window so that you can read your output.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagnostics;


Trace.WriteLine("This line will show on Output window"); 
Trace.Flush();
```

This works on Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

[Refer to microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815788/how-to-trace-and-debug-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 0):

The Output window of Visual Studio 2017 have a menu called ***Show output from***, in my case **ASP.NET Core Web Server**  was the option to select in order to see the printed out, I came across this issue since I had it set to **Build** so I wasn't seeing the printed out lines at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible problems are:

- Firstly, you have not used the `using System` which should be before writing code that uses "System class", as `Console.WriteLine()`
- Secondly, you have not coded what happens after the Console displays "Test"

The possible solution will be:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public static Main()
    {
        //Print to the console
        Console.WriteLine("Test");

        //Allow user to read output
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It is also strategic to code `Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");` on the line that precedes the `Console.ReadKey();` to make the user aware that the program is ending, he/she must press any key to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Change the execution mode to "Self Hosted". In this case, the execution console will appear and all the messages will be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem. What I found on my **VS Community 2022** is that you need to add `Console.ReadLine()`, that way the compiler shows it on the **terminal window**.

So if you wrote for example **"Hello World"** and all you saw was your file directory, with `Console.Readline()` it shows the actual **"Hello World" string.**

It's the way **Visual Studio compilers** work. usually on online compilers `Console.Readline()` will not be needed, might even be taken for an **error**!