# C# console output not working

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am new to c# and encountered a slight problem when trying to display the output

When I type in: Help,? or stats no output is shown

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'Help' to see list of commands");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ParseInput(string input)
    {
        if (input.Contains("help") || input == "?")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Available commands");
            Console.WriteLine("====================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Stats - Display player information");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (input == "stats")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current hit points:");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I already added Console.ReadLine(); Still nothing.

Tried to search for other threads like [Console.WriteLine does not show up in Output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669463/console-writeline-does-not-show-up-in-output-window) and [Why doesn't Console.Writeline, Console.Write work in Visual Studio Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480930/why-doesnt-console-writeline-console-write-work-in-visual-studio-express)

Comment: You're not actually calling `ParseInput()` anywhere. Change your second line in `Main()` to be `ParseInput(Console.ReadLine());`.

Comment: Thank you, my man! :D That seemed to clear my issue! Can I upvote a comment? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `ParseInput` function.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type 'Help' to see list of commands");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    ParseInput(input); // call the function to process your input
}

private static void ParseInput(string input)
{
    if (input.Contains("help") || input == "?")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Available commands");
        Console.WriteLine("====================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Stats - Display player information");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else if (input == "stats")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current hit points:");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the value of `ReadLine`

```
var value =   Console.ReadLine();
ParseInput(value);
```

also to remove being aware  of case use `ToLower`, that way typing "Help" will trigger the logic you want.

```
private static void ParseInput(string input)
{
   input = input.ToLower();
   ....
}
```